# AngularJS & JsonStub

Tags: json, angularjs, api, json-api

We are currently trying to get the Json data from [JsonStub](http://jsonstub.com) using [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). We tried to replicate JsonStub's [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rQkOGHTZEHr5FYVD43my?p=preview) but had no luck getting this to work with our apikeys.

We just want to show `{"message":"hello world!"}` within AngularJS from JsonStub's.

Here is our code, please let me know we're doing wrong.

Thank you.

**Controller**

```
.controller('warrantyListController', function($scope, $http) {
        $http({
              url: 'http://jsonstub.com/jobs',
              method: 'GET',
              dataType: 'json', 
              data: '',         
              headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  'JsonStub-User-Key': 'xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx',
                  'JsonStub-Project-Key': 'xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx'
              }
         })
         .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
         });
 })
```

**JsonStub**
[image]

Comment: Please see the console log for any errors logged.

Comment: Can you try to make request with Postman for chrome. The auth headers may be incorrect.

Comment: @Chandermani I've tried using postman, i've attached a screenshot of what I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do with the fact that its a cross domain request. Open up F12 dev tool and have a look.

---

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://jsonstub.com/jobs. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

---

### Actual Fix

Add the following header

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://jsonstub.com'
```

or, to allow all

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
```

**Possible addition to fix, depending on Angular version**

There has been a know issue in previous versions of Angular with CORS, but it can be resolved with the following config change:

```
.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
 })
```

Comment: Worded a treat, Thank you.